# Nifty Generators LayoutHelper Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on my first Rails project, I used Ryan Bates' Nifty-Generators to create the initial application files. This gives me a `LayoutHelper` with a title method:

```
def title(page_title, show_title = true)
  @content_for_title = page_title.to_s
  @show_title = show_title
end
```

In my homepage view, I have a simple title:

```
<%= title "Welcome" -%>
```

And finally, in my layout (`application.html.erb`), I have:

```
<%- if show_title? -%>
  <h1><%=h yield(:title) %></h1>
<%- end -%>

<%= yield %>
```

What I'm seeing is my title, "Welcome", followed by the value passed (or defaulted to) for `show_title`. I want the former, but not the latter. I understand why the boolean is being implicitly returned by the method, but I didn't expect it to be displayed. The boolean display seems to be appearing as part of the primary content `yield`.

The `yield` command still hasn't really clicked for me yet (I get it, I just don't *get* it, if that makes sense), so I'm hoping someone can help me understand why the boolean is being printed and how I can make it stop. That answer may help me better understand how `yield` works in addition to solving the immediate problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually kind of confused as to why the template calls for `yield(:title)` when you are not doing a `content_for` call anywhere, but are setting an instance variable. Maybe I don't understand enough how yield works as well. Hopefully, Mr. Bates himself will step in here and help out on this one :)

Comment: My knowledge of Ruby is still very much in that awkward, getting-to-know-you phase, but the title method in the LayoutHelper sets the value for @content_for_title. Wouldn't that populate the yield output appropriately or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% title "Welcome" %>
```

You want to call the `title` method, not write out its return value when you call it.